# CORS error when using uploading to GCS from localhost

Tags: cors, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-storage

I'm encountering a CORS error when uploading a file to a [GCS signed url](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) from localhost via `PUT` request, while setting `Content-Type` as `image/png`:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/{{BUCKET_NAME}}/folder/image.png?Expires=1542676226&GoogleAccessId=XXXX&Signature=YYYY' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've made sure to set the bucket's CORS policy as loosely as possible for development purposes:

```
$ gsutil cors get gs://{{BUCKET_NAME}}

[
    {
      "origin": ["*"], // also tried "http://localhost:3000"
      "method": ["*"],
      "responseHeader": ["*"]
    }
]
```

Unfortunately I'm not getting anything other than 403s.

Comment: The fact that you’re getting 403s seems like the problem you need to solve, and the cause should be unrelated to your CORS config. The only effect your CORS config should be having is to add additional headers to response — it should definitely not be making the server block any requests with a 403.

Comment: What method are you using to create the signed URL?

Answer (score 4):

For my case, I use nodejs + `"@google-cloud/storage": "^3.0.2"`

The key is the `version` when you create the signed url. The default version is `v2`

```js
      const getSignedUrlResponse: GetSignedUrlResponse = await file.getSignedUrl({
        action: 'write',
        expires: Date.now() + 60 * 1000
        // version: 'v4'
      });
```

For client, I use `fetch` API, here is the code snippet:

```js
fetch(signedUrl, { method: 'PUT', body: file })
```

Got 403 cors error like this in chrome console:

> PUT https://storage.googleapis.com/ez2on/adminUsers.png?GoogleAccessId=cloud-storage-admin%40shadowsocks-218808.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1562832855&Signature=cllvUH%2FaOxKHDy4GNPcI1FP1BMqbYir08NYFQtxTJ5lpbWBmHkfUgAFx2xfmHjDrzbaIJJ9L8Jntld0YnVIC%2FTHjo3qQC3YNQtr%2B8Jr%2BnT8QuyhAQXBtWAfyvnEfmidF1z0Lz870IiPcgfR2DXDi6XXS1uTVDpasa71O4nttnMR2rzAaB6Ev9IkoxPvZ49dyxjbOOp2aFAHEE9LehHZNRwaRqBl2JJN7rHHtXol%2B%2B8loEu99D3dqj5Ph12Lh7%2BNREG0NarZKZx0Iagw6hW%2BW5rKOCuGyuablvaqgntHpD2WIs2qLCGtU8B1rLhyd4ds5%2F7lHz2AcAZD09uNz%2BKG%2BUA%3D%3D 403
>
> Access to fetch at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/ez2on/adminUsers.png?GoogleAccessId=cloud-storage-admin%40shadowsocks-218808.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1562832855&Signature=cllvUH%2FaOxKHDy4GNPcI1FP1BMqbYir08NYFQtxTJ5lpbWBmHkfUgAFx2xfmHjDrzbaIJJ9L8Jntld0YnVIC%2FTHjo3qQC3YNQtr%2B8Jr%2BnT8QuyhAQXBtWAfyvnEfmidF1z0Lz870IiPcgfR2DXDi6XXS1uTVDpasa71O4nttnMR2rzAaB6Ev9IkoxPvZ49dyxjbOOp2aFAHEE9LehHZNRwaRqBl2JJN7rHHtXol%2B%2B8loEu99D3dqj5Ph12Lh7%2BNREG0NarZKZx0Iagw6hW%2BW5rKOCuGyuablvaqgntHpD2WIs2qLCGtU8B1rLhyd4ds5%2F7lHz2AcAZD09uNz%2BKG%2BUA%3D%3D' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

After I changed `version` from `v2` to `v4`:

```js
      const getSignedUrlResponse: GetSignedUrlResponse = await file.getSignedUrl({
        action: 'write',
        expires: Date.now() + 60 * 1000,
        version: 'v4'
      });
```

The error gone.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I spent an hour struggling with this issue and finally realised that `content-type` is mandatory and that it has to match the content type of the file you are uploading.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually

After setting the correct MIME type on the file the upload was successful.

I used ended up using a library to get the correct MIME type of the file:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types